# Ravendb LoadDocument showing NULL value

Tags: ravendb

I have following two Collections in RavenDB.Please help me for creating index for getting data from both collection.

```
public class Ticket
{
   public string TicketID{get;set;}
   public double Total{get;set;}
}

public class ImportTiming
{
   public string Id{get;set;}
   public DateTime ExtractTime{get;set;}
}

AND

public class ResultClass
   {
      public string TicketID{get;set;}
      public double Total{get;set;}
      public DateTime ExtractTime{get;set;}
   }
```

TicketID(Ticket) & Id(ImportTiming) are same.I am using LoadDocument for ExtractTime but it is showing NULL value.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got solution...
Bellow is the Map-Reduce function,in which i have used LoadDocument<> for selecting data from ImportTiming Document.

```
public class IdxJoinBetweenCollections : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Ticket,JoinBetweenCollections.ResultClass>
    {
        public IdxJoinBetweenCollections()
        {
            Map = docs => from doc in docs
                         let TimeDoc = LoadDocument<ImportTiming>("ImportTiming/" + doc.TicketID)
                          select new
                          {
                              ID = doc.TicketID,
                              Total = doc.Total,   
                              ExtractTime = TimeDoc.ExtractComplete,
                          };
            Reduce = results => from res in results
                                group res by res.ID into g
                                select new
                                {
                                    ID = g.Key, 
                                    Total = g.Select(x => x.Total).FirstOrDefault(),                                                                       
                                    ExtractTime = g.Select(x => x.ExtractTime).FirstOrDefault(),

                                };
        }
    }
```

In LoadDocument("ImportTiming/" + doc.TicketID),i have used CollectionName followed by Id so that i gets whole document.If i dont use CollectionName then it shows NULL value.
Reference:http://ravendb.net/docs/2.0/client-api/querying/static-indexes/indexing-related-documents